# Modelica assert(condition, message, level=AssertionLevel.warning);

Tags: assert, modelica

Part 8.3.7 of the Modelica Spec describes the function `assert` and gives two examples, but whenever I try to use one of the following commands, it does not work as expected:

```
assert(T > 250 and T < 400, 
    "Medium model outside full accuracy range", 
    AssertionLevel.warning);
```

or

```
assert(T > 250 and T < 400, 
    "Medium model outside full accuracy range", 
    level=AssertionLevel.warning);
```

What is wrong here? Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I checked with Dymola (2012FD01) and it looks like Dymola has not implemented the `level` argument:

```
> document("assert")
function assert "assert that a condition is true"
input Boolean _condition;
input String _error;

The given condition should be true.
If it is false an error message will be given
end assert;
```

Or maybe it's simply not documented. You probably should ask the DS support on that. In OpenModelica it seems they have implemented as described in the specs (see also http://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/assert.html).

Comment: Dymola support has respondend and confirmed that the level argument is not (yet?) supported.

Comment: Update: New versions of Dymola do support the level argument.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state what tool you are using, but I would point out that this is a relatively new syntax for assert.  You might try without the "level" indicator (i.e. just two arguments: a Boolean and a String).

Comment: The tool is Dymola 2012 FD01. If I use boolean+string only it works. But AFAIK `assert` issues an error by default and thus halts the simulation!?